SSMS Won't Show Databases in the Explorer Tree for a Specific SQL Server Account
When logging in as a specific SQL Server user, I was unable to view all the databases in the SSMS Explorer tree. Originally, I thought this was a SQL Server user account problem. I examined the Login definition, the User definition, I compared the User row across the various databases in question. Everything matches.
Subsequently, it became evident to me that the problem is with SSMS, or perhaps some underlying table that SSMS uses to render its Explorer tree. Because the databases are in fact available to this user. (This user happens to be in the db_owner role for the databases in question and in fact owns several schemas in these databases. This user cannot be dropped from these databases.)
So here's what I see when logging in as the user in question. The SSMS Explorer tree only shows me the master and rater8 databases. There are two other databases on this server but these are not shown in the Explorer tree. However, when I go to a Query window and drop down the Database selector I see all four databases as expected.

When I log in with this same SQL Server account using Azure Data Studio, I see all four databases as expected.

Any idea why SQL Server is having trouble rendering those other two databases for this particular user account? The issue is account dependent. When I log via SSMS using several different accounts I am able to see all four databases in the SSMS Explorer tree, as expected. Here's a screenshot of what I see when I log in using a different account:

Any idea what is causing the breakdown in the SSMS Explorer tree for one particular SQL Server account? Thanks for your advice!

Please look at this answer (reproduced below) on Stack Overflow by Joseph Xu:

I think you'd better check the Options settings, did you specify the db name. If so, you will only can see specified db, not all.


